# Android: How to set a Filter to a Adapter and ListView

Tags: android, listview, filter, adapter

I have a ListView where I put a list of restaurants. Then I added a filter to my custom Adpter. When I put some text in a EditText field I only see the restaurant I asked for. So the filter works. 
But I have a problem!!

Let's suppose my ListView is made up of this 5 Restaurants:

## ROW| Restaurant

1    | John
2    | Rino
3    | Paul
4    | Gino
5    | Micheal

Let's say I am searching for "ino", the filter will show me:

## Row | Restaurant

1   | Rino
2   | Gino

Here is the problem! When I click on "Rino" I get the row number "1" which is the one filtered .. but I need to have "2" which is "the real" row for Rino.
And so, If I click on "Gino" I get "2" Whereas I need to get "4" which is "the real row" for Gino. (look at the the first table I wrote)

I need to do this.. I click on a restaurant's name and I want to see all the details about that restaurant. But using the filter I am getting a wrong restaurant row number... and a different restaurant detail! What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

What you got is the normal behavior of `OnItemClickListener`.

You need to override the `public Object getItem(int positon)` method of your adapter.
This method should return the object from which you display datas in row `position`.

Then you use the following to acces desired datas :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Object object = yourAdapter.getItemp(position);
    // do whatever you want with the object
}
```

Comment: hum OK! IT seems interesting. I'll try to do what you told me.. Thank so much

Comment: Hello I am back again. I was on vacation so I could reply sooner :)
I tried to follow your tips but I cant make it work.
I am using this adapter : https://gist.github.com/fjfish/3024308
and I modified it like that:

public Object getItem(int position)
return originalData // this is the array where originl data is stored
//

and in event onItemClick i Do the following:

Object c = adapter.getItem(position)

but what I get is the complete list of all the item inside my array and not what I clicked on ..
How can I solve it? I am sorry ,,, my Java is really really poor

Comment: Your `getItem`method should return the item at the position not the entire array. Try `return originalData[position]`

Answer (score 0):

See the following links :

1. [Android Search Filter ListView Images and Texts Tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-filter-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/)
2. [Android ListView : Custom Filter and Filterable interface](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html)
3. [Android ListView with Custom Layout and Filter example](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-custom-layout-filter.html)